# Rails: Using multiple checkboxes for single field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

I have a form with multiple checkboxes and I'd like to combine their values into a string before saving to the database.  I've designed my form like:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@health_profile) do |f| %>

    <% @hp_prior.medications.split(", ").each do |med| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "health_profile[medications][]", med, false, id: med, multiple: true %>
        <label for="<%= med %>"><%= med.capitalize %></label>
    <% end -%>

<% end -%>
```

In my controller I've changed `:medications` to accept an array:

```
def health_profile_params
    params.require(:health_profile).permit(:medications => [])
end
```

But I run into an issue with the data because the submitted form params come through as:

```
Parameters: {... "health_profile"=>{"medications"=>["zyrtec for allergies", "advil"]}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

But after calling `HealthProfile.new(health_profile_params)` the record appears as:

```
#<HealthProfile:0x007fb08fe64488> {... :medications => "[\"zyrtec for allergies\", \"advil\"]"}
```

**How can I combine these values so that the final `@health_profile` looks like:**

```
#<HealthProfile:0x007fb08fe64488> {... :medications => "zyrtec for allergies, advil"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a custom setter for the attribute on your model:

```
def medications=(value)
  value = value.join(', ') if value.is_a?(Array)
  write_attribute :medications, value
end
```

Comment: ...I really did not expect that to work since it seems like a String on the model.  I guess I need to read up on setters!  Glad it does!

Comment: You saw that string because you were setting an array on a string attribute and rails serialized the array by default (you saw the resulting value after being serialized). With this setter, you actually control the array as it came from the request and then serialize it the way you want instead, that's why it works.